Appropriate regression analysis for intervention study using waiting-list control design
Consider a randomized trial with the following design: After a baseline measurement ($T_0$), subjects are randomized into a control group ($G_0$) and an intervention group ($G_1$). The intervention group receives the treatment while the controls are on a waiting-list (no treatment). At $T_1$, both groups are assessed. In the second period, the controls on the waiting-list now receive the treatment and are assessed again at $T_2$. The intervention group does not participate in period 2. The following figure illustrates the design:

I want to answer the following questions (marked by corresponding numbers in the diagram):

Compare the means at $T_1$ between the two groups.
Compare the means of the control group at $T_2$ with the intervention group at $T_1$.
Compare the means of the control group at $T_2$ with that at $T_1$ (within-group).

Q1: What regression model would you consider most appropriate to answer these question?
Due to the nature of repeated measurements, I've thought about a mixed model of the form:
$$
y = (\beta_0 + b_0) + \beta_1T_1 + \beta_2T_2G_0+ \beta_3T_1G_1
$$
where $T_1$ and $T_2$ are indicators for the time points and $G_0$ and $G_1$ are indicators for the control and intervention group, and $b_0$ is a random intercept. This model forces the fitted means at $T_0$ to be identical for both groups, which is reasonable due to the design (randomization happens after the first measurement).
If my reasoning is correct, my three questions could be answered with the following tests of coefficients or contrasts:

$\beta_3 = 0$
$\beta_1 + \beta_3 -\beta_2 = 0$
$\beta_1 - \beta_2 = 0$

I've conducted some simulations which seem to confirm my thinking (I could post the code if there is interest) but I wonder if there is an easier way to parametrize the problem.
Q2: Does this sound reasonable or is there an easier parametrization for this?

Is time=0 being modelled, or is it an adjustment variable?

@DemetriPananos In the proposed mixed model, $T_0$ is modelled through $\beta_0$ if I'm not mistaken. So it's not an ANCOVA-type model where $T_0$ (or even $T_1$ for $T_2$ in the control group) serves as an adjustment. Although this crossed my mind also. I'd be very interested if this would provide any benefits.

Ok, thanks.  So I don't think modelling the T0 outcome is useful here unless you want to understand how that  would vary by other adjustment variables, in which case I think you could run a much simpler regression.  If you instead used the T0 as an adjustment variable, the approach might be simpler (certainly the model would be) and you would potentially gain precision if T0 is at all correlated with other variables.  However, you would probably have to forgo a mixed effect approach since the T0 measurement is going to be perfectly correlated with the random effect.

@DemetriPananos Thanks, that's useful info and makes sense. If you could flesh out the detail in an answer, I'd be happy to accept it. Would you use $T_0$ to adjust for both $T_1$ and $T_2$ (only for controls) or would you use $T_1$ to adjust for $T_2$?

I'll flesh out an answer and you can decide if it is appropriate for your needs or not.

While I think this could be handled with a mixed effects model, it might be simpler (from an analysis standpoint) to do the following:

Don't model $T_0$.  From the design, we know $E[y \mid t = T_0, g=1] = E[y \mid t = T_0, g=0]$, so we could use this as an adjustment variable instead.  This would preclude a mixed effect model however, since now the random effect would be perfectly correlated with this outcome.
Compare time points as needed in multiple models as opposed to one big model.  This is conceptually simpler.  The main benefit of the mixed effect approach is an increase in precision since you get to estimate the within subject uncertainty.  If the outcome at T0 is correlated with other outcomes, you get a similar (though not altogether identical) benefit.

Let's simulate some data and see how this works.  In the following code, I simulate a set of potential outcomes over the 3 timepoints.  The potential outcomes are independent across exposure but are correlated across time with covariance matrix Bigma.  I then randomize subjects to either control or treatment, and select the potential outcomes accordingly.
library(tidyverse)

n_subjects <- 100

rho <- diag(3)
rho[1, 2] <- rho[2, 1] <- 0.5
rho[1, 3] <- rho[3, 1] <- 0.4
rho[2, 3] <- rho[3, 2] <- 0.7
sigma_var <- c(0.3, 0.3, 0.3) # You can edit this to see what happens when the sd changes
Bigma <- diag(sigma_var) %*% rho %*% diag(sigma_var)

# Potential outcomes under no treatment
Y0 <- MASS::mvrnorm(
  n = n_subjects, 
  mu = c(0, 0.25, 0.5), # Progression of outcomes over time,
  Sigma = Bigma
)

# Potential outcomes under treatment
ate <- 0.5
Y1 <- MASS::mvrnorm(
  n = n_subjects, 
  mu = c(0, 0.25 + ate, 0.5 + ate), # Progression of outcomes over time,
  Sigma = Bigma
)

# Randomize subjects
ids <- 1:n_subjects
g <- sample(rep(0:1, each=n_subjects/2))

d <- tibble(ids, g)

# Add the outcome variables using the switching equation
y <- map2_dfr(d$ids, d$g, ~{
  
  y <- c(
    Y0[.x, 1], # In the baseline period, we observe the Y(0) potential outcome,
    if_else(.y == 0, Y0[.x, 2],  Y1[.x, 2]), # In period 1, obvserve y(0) only for contorls,
    Y1[.x, 3] # In third period, observe Y(1) for everyone
  )
  as_tibble(t(y))
  
})



md <- bind_cols(d, y)   %>% 
     mutate(
       # WE don't have the last time point for the exposure group
       V3 = if_else(g==1, NA, V3)
     ) 

Using these data, we can answer your questions as follows.
1. Compare the means at $T_1$ between the two groups.
This is fairly simple under the given approach.  I will use a linear model, but you could easily use any GLM appropriate for your outcome.

fit <- lm(V2 ~ V1 + g, data = md)
summary(fit)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = V2 ~ V1 + g, data = md)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
#> -0.75443 -0.16940  0.00092  0.17418  0.62932 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)  0.23665    0.04306   5.496 3.14e-07 ***
#> V1           0.33287    0.09514   3.499 0.000708 ***
#> g            0.53231    0.06076   8.760 6.34e-14 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.3032 on 97 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:   0.49,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.4794 
#> F-statistic: 46.59 on 2 and 97 DF,  p-value: 6.585e-15


The estimand for the coefficient of g (exposure) should be the ATE (assuming the waiting has no impact on the outcome, which is sensible). The estimate for g is fairly close to the actual value for the ATE of 0.5, so that's good.  Additionally, the standard error for the estimate is smaller than it would be otherwise since V1 (the outcome at baseline) is correlated with V2 (the outcome at time 1).
2. Compare the means of the control group at $T_2$ with the intervention group at $T_1$.
This requires some data wrangling in order to appropriately filter the data.
# 2
q2d <- md %>% 
       pivot_longer(
         V2:V3, 
         names_to = 'timept', 
         values_to = 'y'
       ) %>% 
  filter( (g==1 & timept == 'V2') | (g==0 & timept == 'V3'))

fit <-  lm(y ~ g + V1, data = q2d)
summary(fit)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = y ~ g + V1, data = q2d)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
#> -0.80309 -0.23521 -0.02147  0.21227  0.85513 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)  1.01417    0.04653  21.795  < 2e-16 ***
#> g           -0.29753    0.06637  -4.483 2.02e-05 ***
#> V1          -0.14864    0.13250  -1.122    0.265    
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.3289 on 97 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.1922, Adjusted R-squared:  0.1756 


Note that the treatment effect is NOT close to the ATE.  This is because we would not be comparing like with like.  In order to get a valid estimate of the treatment effect, we would need to compare the outcomes at T2 between groups.  This should be clear from the DAG you've written.  Since you don't have outcomes for treatment at time 2, you can't do this.
However, the estimate for g is very  close to what the difference between groups would be (which is 0.25).
Alternatively, you could include the interaction between g and V1 and use marginaleffects::avg_comparisons(fit, variables = 'g')  to estimate the marginal effect of g integrating over V1.
3. Compare the means of the control group at $T_2$ with that at $T_1$ (within-group).
Again, some mild data wrangling to get the right form.  Since this is effectively a paired design, let's run a regression of V3 on V2 and V1.  This would be a full ancova type approach
# 3


q3d <- md %>% 
       filter(g==0)


fit <- lm(V3 ~ V2 + V1, data = q3d)
summary(fit)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = V3 ~ V2 + V1, data = q3d)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
#> -0.48317 -0.22421  0.00916  0.18866  0.58235 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)  0.94593    0.05768  16.400   <2e-16 ***
#> V2           0.05068    0.14700   0.345    0.732    
#> V1           0.02561    0.13448   0.190    0.850    
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.2756 on 47 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.008312,   Adjusted R-squared:  -0.03389 
#> F-statistic: 0.197 on 2 and 47 DF,  p-value: 0.8219

You could also take the differences between V3 and V2 here and regress those on V1.  This would require making the appropriate assumptions (e.g. that the regression coefficient of for V2 on V1 is exactly 1.  I think Frank Harrell has written on this here).  That would look like
#alternatively
q3d <- md %>% 
       filter(g==0) %>% 
       mutate(
         delta_v = V3 - V2
       )

fit <- lm(delta_v ~ 1, data = q3d)
summary(fit)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = delta_v ~ 1, data = q3d)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
#> -1.16167 -0.27947 -0.06026  0.23143  0.83300 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#> (Intercept)  0.76425    0.06131   12.47   <2e-16 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.4335 on 49 degrees of freedom

This analysis, though it makes stronger assumptions, is much more transparent.  From the simulation, we know that the difference in outcome in control group between times 2 and 1 is 1 - 0.25 = 0.75, and our estimate reflects this.
Let me know if this answers the questions you need answered. I can edit as needed, but this is conceptually simpler than modelling all outcomes at once (especially the baseline outcome, which you don't need to model as a function of exposure).

Thanks for this comprehensive answer. I have a couple of follow-up questions: 1) So you're saying there is little downside to model each question separately instead of one single model? 2) The progression for the control group in your simulations is 0, 0.25, 0.5, right? But they are treated after $T_1$ so shouldn't their last mean be 1? 3) Shouldn't the result for question 3 be 0.25 at the moment? Or how can I read the estimated difference from the output?


From what you've told me, I see little downside to answering each question separately, unless you need within subject variability estimates. 2) Ack, yes you are correct.  I should change that in the simulation. 3) The answer to question 3 depends on what the outcomes for the previous two measurements were.  You could also do a difference between V3 and V2 and analyze that (omitting V1).  That would also answer the question.

I'll edit my simulation

@COOLSerdash I've edited my simulation to be aligned with your design
